# calling page methods using web workkers

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call page methods using web workers.

```
Button_click{
var worker = new Worker('m_statusworker.js');

  }
```

In m_statusworker.js

```
PageMethods.changeTableStatus(CRStatusSuccess, CRStatusfailed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

You can listen for events from the worker and run a function when you get one.

```
worker..addEventListener("message", function (oEvent) {
  PageMethods.changeTableStatus(oEvent.data.CRStatusSuccess, oEvent.data.CRStatusfailed);
}, false);
```

Comment: In simple words, the PageMethods varible is not defined inside the worker's script enviroment.